# getting this error when i try to use the elif key word please

Tags: python

Showing Syntax errors while using elif when there are no empty lines or spaces left need help.
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abTPZ.png)

```
>>> def Fibonacci(n):
        if n<0:
            print ("incorrect input")
            elif n==1:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Comment: You should consider the indentation for `elif` and the statement for that condition.

Comment: Can you embed the image in your post and describe your issue a little more? Having link only posts makes questions harder to find, answer, and keep up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using elif in indented block which implies a new if-elif block. So if you are using `elif` it can be used only after an `if` statement in that block. But if the `elif` is concerned with the earlier used `if` for outer block then you should indent the `elif` to match with the `if`statement